# Pass value from ajax to Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Apps Script and I'm trying to make a web app where I can pass the value from Ajax to my script's web app. I'm able to execute it directly from the web app but it's not working from my webpage. Here are my codes,

**Webpage's JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#btnGet').click(function () {
    var getId = $('#text').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbwpkBW7qKZBeJ011C7j3le4vV8D0SEHu9709mWtEMzJgrJmHnaR/exec",
      data: getId,
      type: "GET",
      crossDomain: true,
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("Success!");
      },
      error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        alert("Failed!");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

**Google Apps Script**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var html ="<input type='text' id='text' /><br><br><input type='button' id='btnGet' onclick='myClick()' value='submit' /><br><br>";
  html+="<script>";
  html+="document.getElementById('btnGet').onclick = function() { var e = document.getElementById('text').value; google.script.run.newEntry(e); }</script>";
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}

function newEntry(text) {
  Logger.log(text);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(text);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  sheet.getRange(lr+1, 1, 1, 3).setValues([["First Name", "Last Name", "Email"]]);
}
```

How can I pass the value from ajax to my apps script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try appending the data you're sending out onto the end of the url:

`"ScriptUrl/exec?getIdKey=getIdValue"`

[Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content) for that.

Your `data` property is likely just being ignored.

The value can then be accessed in `doGet(e)` with:

`var getIdValue = e.parameter.getIdKey`

[Docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web?hl=en#url_parameters) for that

Comment: Thanks. But still it's not working. Please see my updates.

Comment: I've also tried sending data onto the end of the url, still doesn't work. I've tried logging the value. It seems it's getting it from my webpage, but for some reason sheet is not updating.

Comment: Are you expecting a .gs Web App to update live while it's open in another window or some thing before the data ultimately gets passed on to `newEntry()`?

Comment: No, I just want to run the web app through my webpage.

Comment: Is the app embedded via iframe inside of your web page? You shouldn't be able to even see any of the .gs web app in your own web page. Even if we could, that embedded app wound't update live with this setup.

Comment: No, it's actually a chrome extension, the values are taken from the html page of the extension.

Comment: returning `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput()` is only for Google Script web apps. Not for Chrome exts to use. Change it to `ContentService.createTextOutput(content)` as shown in the docs I linked to and go from there.

Comment: Yes, this worked. I think I finally figured it out how the web app works. Thanks a lot for your time! :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to make a page redirection and navigate to the script's published url on a click or something

> because XHR requests to the Google Apps Script server are forbidden

From an external client XHR requests are forbidden but within the Google App Script editor calls to server side scripts(i.e. any one of the functions in .gs file) are by default asynchronous and can be made using `google.script.run`

For more please refer to the official documentation.

[Google App Script Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions)

Comment: OP was not trying to make an XHR request from a .gs web app. It was from a Chrome Ext html page.

Comment: I know that's why I pointed him to Restrictions page. Chrome Ext being an external client can not make a XHR request to app script, for making XHR request it must be made from within Google App Script Environment.

Comment: "_An extension can talk to remote servers outside of its origin, as long as it first requests cross-origin permissions._" - [chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr). OP is using `crossDomain: true,` in his ext

Comment: I know that an extension can make XHR request to outside server but not to  App Acript Server, that's the same restriction I am talking about.

Comment: please look at the comments in my answer and at the bottom of the 1st doc I linked to as `ContentService` in GS will handle requests initiated from anywhere. `google.script.run` will not apply in this case either.

Comment: and you please read my answer carefully, I never said it will work in this case, what I am saying is that google.script.run works with script editor which is a synchronous call by default but external asynchronous call are not allowed, what I am saying is that google.script.run is the closet you can get in making a asynchronous call. External async call to app script is not allowed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104198/discussion-between-raghvendra-kumar-and-bryan-p).